# Why this mismatch between Format & Convert SQl functions for Hijri Date :

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, date-formatting, hijri

**In SQl Server 2016 :**

`Convert` & `Format` for Hijri date are giving different results.

The output of `Format` function is correct.

```
Declare @Date Datetime = '02/08/2018'
Select CONVERT(nchar, @Date, 131)   -- outputs 23/05/1439 12:00:00:000AM     
SELECT FORMAT ( @Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'ar-SA' ) -- outputs 22/05/1439
```

I have two questions :

1) Why this difference ?

2) How do I use `Format` in SQL Server 2008 R2. Any alternative ?

Comment: try using a format that is language neutral, like `yyyyMMdd`. For example `@Date = '20180802'`

Comment: maybe this can help http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: @GuidoG Still the same result.Used iso format yyyyMMdd.

Answer (score 0):

1) Not all gregorian-hijri converters show same result on web. For example, according to [this](http://www.islamicity.org/hijri-gregorian-converter/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#) result is `23/05/1439`, but according to [this](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=dateconverter) result is `22/05/1439`. In the same way `convert` and `format` functions might be using different converting algorithms. That's only my guess.

2) Create own calendar table with values that you think are correct